# hidden list box not showing after javascript

Tags: javascript

So I'm pretty baffled with this issue I have here. I'm almost certain this code is correct yet the list box that I want to appear is not showing up at all after something is selected from the first drop down box. Here is what I have going for the code now

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>


<link href="css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function view_private_user_list(){
    var i = document.status.private_users.options[document.status.private_users.selectedIndex].value;

    if(i == 1){
        document.getElementById('private_select_now').style.visibility="visible";
    } else{
        document.getElementById('private_select_now').style.visibility="visible";
    }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="show_private_option">

<select id="private_users" onChange="view_private_user_list()">
<option value="0" SELECTED>Select user....</option>
<option value="1">Vincent</option>
</select>

<div id="private_select_now" style="visibility:hidden">
<select size="3">
<option value="">{#template_dlg.select}...</option>

<option value="SOOOOLDmax.htm">SOOOOLDmax</option>
<option value="mike.htm">tester</option>               
</select>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fiddle should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/3XENR/1/

I think the way you're trying to find out the current value of the dropdown doesn't quite work.

Try this version of the function instead.

```
function view_private_user_list(){
    var selectEl = document.getElementById('private_users');
    var i = selectEl.value;

    if(i == 1){
        document.getElementById('private_select_now').style.visibility="visible";
    } else{
        document.getElementById('private_select_now').style.visibility="hidden";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vero that did the trick. Why is it that my previous function was not changing the hidden attribute?

Comment: Where did you get this from "document.status"? I looked it up on the internet and can't find it.

Comment: so i used "document.getElementById" instead. if - everywhere you use document.status.private_users - you replace that with document.getElementById('private_users'), your code would work as well!

Comment: except you also need to change the style.visibility to "hidden" in the else clause ;)

Answer (score 0):

instead of visibility, use display

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function view_private_user_list(){
var i = document.getElementById('private_users').selectedIndex.value
    if(i == 1){
        document.getElementById('private_select_now').style.display="block";
    } else{
        document.getElementById('private_select_now').style.display="none";
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I went ahead and changed the style attribute to display as well as the javascript function to display and still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

document.getElementById('private_select_now').style.display ="block";
and
document.getElementById('private_select_now').style.display="none";

instead